# Docker shows inconsistent behaviour when creating container from image

Tags: unix, testing, docker, virtualization, lamp

I am developing a web application which depends on a moodle system, as it uses moodles webservices. For my automated tests, I wanted to use docker to provide a preconfigured moodle-application on all my machines. Therefore I created a docker image, which I import from a .tar.gz file.

However, creating a new container-instance from this image behaves inconsistently. Sometimes the container boots up correctly and everything works fine. However, sometimes the container starts but the moodle-website is not reachable. If I connect my bash to the container using `docker exec -it <container> bash` I see that apache is running. The error logs do not show any entries which might be related to this issue.

If I kill the container instance and boot it up again, everything works as expected (sometimes this step has to be repeated multiple times). Do you have any idea what could be the reason for this strange behaviour? Anyone experiencing similar issues?

Docker is running on Ubuntu 14:04. The problem appears on several machines. The script which imports the image and starts the container looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker rm -f moodle
docker load < my-moodle.tar.gz
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -p 8443:443 -p 3306:3306 --name moodle moodle-image
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successful container startup depends on your container entrypoint and external resources (if the entrypoint has external dependencies). What is the entrypoint? Does it depend on external resources?

Comment: The entrypoint did not really depend on any external ressources, but it seems like this is a problem related to my specific configuration, rather than a general bug, so I resolved it by setting up another image. Thanks for your help. :)